# Popular DropDownList e fazer insert com o valor escolhido

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

No meu DB eu tenho 3 tabelas:

```
- Genero(IdGenero,Genero,Descricao)
- Publicação(IdPublicacao, Titulo, Sinopse,IdUsuario) 
- PublicaçãoGenero(IdPublicacaoGenero,IdPublicacao,IdGenero)
```

Esta últma faz a ligação entre as duas primeiras.

A minha primeira dúvida é: Como popular a `DropDownList` com os valores da tabela Genero (Os generos já estão gravados no banco)? Eu cheguei a fazer desta maneira:

Na Action de Criar Publicação eu coloquei a seguinte linha

```
ViewBag.Genero = new SelectList(db.Genero, "IdGenero", "Genero1", pg.IdPublicacao);
```

E na view eu fiz assim:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Genero", ViewBag.Genero as SelectList, "Selecione um Genero")
```

Porém, eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Genero'

Minha segunda dúvida:

Como pegar o id de qual genero o usuario escolheu, para poder fazer o insert na terceira tabela (`PublicacaoGenero`)?

Edit:

Esse é meu controller responsável por criar a publicação.

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CriarPub(Publicacao pub)
        {
            PublicacaoGenero pg = new PublicacaoGenero();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               ViewBag.Generos= db.Genero.ToList();
               pub.DtCriacao = DateTime.Now;
               db.Publicacao.Add(pub);
               pg.IdPublicacao = pub.IdPublicacao;
               pg.IdGenero = //aqui entraria o id do genero selecionado na dropdownlist
               db.SaveChanges();
               return RedirectToAction("Index", "Usuario");
            }
            return View(pub);
        }
```

Não sei se faço da maneira correta, mas é assim que eu costumo fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente fazer da maneira antiga. É um pouco mais prolixa, mas funciona sempre:

```
ViewBag.Generos = db.Genero.ToList();
```

### View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GeneroId, ((IEnumerable<Genero>)ViewBag.Generos).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
    Text = option.Nome, 
    Value = option.Id.ToString(), 
    Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.GeneroId == option.Id)
}), "Selecione um Genero")
```

### Controller, método `POST`

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CriarPub(Publicacao pub)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           pub.DtCriacao = DateTime.Now;
           db.Publicacao.Add(pub);

           var pg = new PublicacaoGenero();

           // Esqueça essa construção. Esse tipo de atribuição pode provocar 
           // uma inclusão do registro em duplicidade.
           // pg.IdPublicacao = pub.IdPublicacao;
           // pg.IdGenero = //aqui entraria o id do genero selecionado na dropdownlist

           // Primeiro carregue o Genero no seu contexto e depois atribua o objeto
           // (não o Id) diretamente no objeto que está sendo criado.
           pg.Genero = db.Genero.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Id == pub.GeneroId);
           pg.Publicacao = pub;
           db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Usuario");
        }

        // A ViewBag é preenchida fora porque serve para o MVC refazer a View
        // caso ela seja inválida.
        ViewBag.Generos= db.Genero.ToList();
        return View(pub);
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado. Consegui colocar para funcionar! Mas em relação a minha segunda pergunta. Como faço para pegar esse id selecionado e jogar no banco?

Comment: @RyanSantos Depende da lógica do seu Controller. Como você não colocou na pergunta como pretende salvar seu Model, não respondi essa parte, mas edite sua pergunta e deixe um comentário pra mim que complemento a resposta.

Comment: Confere se ficou mais claro, por favor.

Comment: @RyanSantos Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Ainda não testei pois estou na rua. Mas no meu caso, eu criei a tabela PublicacaoGenero  para permitir que a publicação tenha mais de um gênero (2 na verdade). Então na minha tabela publicação eu não tenho a coluna GeneroID e na tabela PublicacaoGenero só deixei os ids  mesmo. Seria necessário colocar o nome do gênero nessa tabela?

Comment: @RyanSantos Não precisa.